# UITableView swipe gesture requires near perfect accuracy

Tags: ios, cocoa, tableview, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I'm working on a custom swipe event for a UITableView that uses custom UITableViewCell subclass. I included the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in my header, and have this in `viewDidLoad:`

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

My swipeLeft method looks like so:

```
-(void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
        NSDictionary *clip = [self.clips objectAtIndex:swipedIndexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Swiped!");


    }
}
```

It's *sort* of working, but the swipe has to be incredibly precise. Like nearly impossibly precise.

I almost got it working by using a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead, but unfortunately it didn't play nice with the global side drawer component that uses a global pan gesture recognizer (ECSlidingViewController for those interested).

Is there any way around this? Any help would be appreciated, as I've been googling around and browsing SO for hours looking for a solution.

Comment: So is the point for the user to swipe on a specific cell, or the tableview itself?

Comment: @MishieMoo A cell, but I read it's better practice to implement the GR on the whole tableview and use CG point to get the cell that was swiped.

Comment: As a side note I did try and apply it just to a cell but I was getting the exact same problem.

Comment: So what *exactly* is the problem? Is it finding the wrong cell? Or are you unable to get a good point for the swipe?

Comment: @MishieMoo It's about the swipe requiring far too precise of a swipe. The swiping almost has to be perfectly horizontal, which is near impossible to naturally do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by [Kolin Krewinkel](https://twitter.com/kkrewink) on Twitter, implementing these 2 delegate methods did the trick:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This initially worked for me, but after making a subclass for my tableview, I also had to call requireGestureRecognizerToFail on all of my tableview's preexisting recognizers.  Otherwise the vertical and horizontal recognizers interfered with each other.  Hopefully that can save someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using the ECSlidingViewController and swipe-to-delete on a UITableView (the top view controller in my case slides to the left to reveal the menu).

I fixed the problem by adding a delegate to the default `panGesture` property of my `ECSlidingViewController` like this to only pull in the menu if the swipe starts in the very right-hand edge of the screen:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if ([gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view].x > ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 60.0))
  {
    return YES;
  }
return NO;
}
```