# UISwipeGestureRecognizer in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add swipe left recognition to the table headers only.
Doesn't seem to work- tried everything found on stackoverflow and web.
Works fine on the actual table cells, but when adding it to the table headers... nothing.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{
    SnapSong *song = nil;
    NSString *text = song.title;
    NSString *detailedText = song.albumName;

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 80)];
view.backgroundColor = [[Globals sharedInstance] gCellBgColor];
view.tag = section;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

return view;
```

}

It just wouldn't swipe, I've tried adding gesture to the table etc...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try to set the view.userInteractionEnabled = YES

Comment: tried, didn't work.
For some reason i am able to swipe like once every X tries, randomly.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890305/uitableview-swipe-gesture-requires-near-perfect-accuracy

Comment: Can you post your `handleSwipeLeft:` method? Have you debugged that execution enters the handler method when you try to swipe?

Comment: I've a log printing out the first line of HandleSwipe.. method,it gets there like I said once every X swipes, randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got the fricking thing working, this what did the trick

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
**[recognizer setDelegate:self];**
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and had to add 2 functions:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
  {
  return YES;
  }

And of course in the .h file add the delegate

```
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```